# ClassCast Exception in SOAPUI JDBC Request cant be cast to Rest Request

Tags: soapui

When I try to run my JDBC request in SOAPUI I am getting the below error.

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcRequest cannot be cast to com.eviware.soapui.impl.rest.RestRequest

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about your test case and how you're using the JDBC request? What's your SQL query?

Comment: update tableA
set cola='1'
where colb='${#TestCase#property1}' and colb='${#TestCase#property2}' 
 property1 and property2 are project level properties.                                                                                                             
  We submit XML inquiry through REST and validate Response through Assertions.   sorry..Actually the application am working deals with sensitive data.So couldn't give much detail. Pls let me know exactly what to be shared..will try to share it

Comment: You say `property1` and `property2` are project-level properties, but they're referenced in your update statement as test-case properties. Is that correct? Are you able to post the relevant part of your soapUI error log?